# Cannot find symbol androidx.car.app.SessionInfo

Tags: android, automotive

I am trying to write an app for Android Automotive OS and am replicating an example from this git: https://github.com/android/car-samples
I am specifically trying to build the HelloWorldService for Automotive.

But I cant seem to get the SessionsInfo import working
[image: sessioninfo]

I can see the others inside the androidx.car.app are available. Any idea why the sessioninfo is not found?
I am running Android Studio Electric Eal 2022.1.1 Patch 2, Gradle JDK is set to "Android Studio default JDK - 11.0.15"

Answer (score 1):

Update your dependency to version to (at least) 1.3.0-alpha01:

inside file `build.gradle` replace

`implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.2.0-rc01"`

by

`implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.3.0-alpha01"`

The class androidx.car.app.SessionInfo was introduced on version  1.3.0-alpha01

https://androidx.tech/artifacts/car.app/app/1.3.0-alpha01-source/androidx/car/app/SessionInfo.java.html

** Edit
Opened a pull request on google repository to fix it
https://github.com/android/car-samples/pull/42